# Justify that $\operatorname{Cov}(y, y^\top\!Ay) = 2\Sigma A\mu$

Tags: statistics, expected-value, covariance, multivariate-statistical-analysis

> If $A$ is a $p \times p$ symmetric matrix of constants, and $y \sim N_p(\mu, \Sigma)$, justify the following result:
> $$
> \newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}
> \Cov(y, y^\top\!Ay) = 2\Sigma A\mu
> $$

I know that I should expand this equation into
$$
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}
\Cov(y, y^\top\!Ay) = \E(yy^\top\!Ay) - \E(y) \E(y^\top\!Ay)
$$
where
$\E(y) = \mu$
and
$$
\E(y^\top\!Ay) = \E(y^\top)\E(Ay) 
= \mu^\top\!A \E(y) = \mu^\top\!A\mu
$$

I need some guidance with how to go about with this term: $\E(yy^\top\!Ay)$.

How does the $\Sigma$ go into the equation?

I attempted the question but I arrived at the answer that the covariance is zero.

Comment: $E(y^\top Ay) = E(y^\top)E(Ay)$ doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these sorts of questions, it is often useful to write $y = \mu + \Sigma^{1/2}z$, where $z \sim N_p(0, 1)$ is a vector of iid standard Gaussians.

Now, we can compute that
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Cov}(y, y^{\mathrm{T}} Ay)
&= \operatorname{Cov}(\mu + \Sigma^{1/2}z, (\mu + \Sigma^{1/2}z)^{\mathrm{T}} A(\mu + \Sigma^{1/2}z)) \\
&= \operatorname{Cov}(\Sigma^{1/2}z, z^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2}z + 2 \mu^{\mathrm{T}}A\Sigma^{1/2}z) \\
&= \operatorname{Cov}(\Sigma^{1/2}z, z^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2}z)
 + 2\operatorname{Cov}(\Sigma^{1/2}z, \mu^{\mathrm{T}}A\Sigma^{1/2}z).
\end{align*}

First, since $z$ is a standard Gaussian, we have that $z \stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{=} -z$, and so
\begin{align*}
  \operatorname{Cov}(\Sigma^{1/2}z, z^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2}z)
  &= \operatorname{Cov}(\Sigma^{1/2}(-z), (-z)^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2}(-z)) \\
  &= -\operatorname{Cov}(\Sigma^{1/2}z, z^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2}z),
\end{align*}
from which it follows that $\operatorname{Cov}(\Sigma^{1/2}z, z^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2}z) = 0$.

Secondly, since $\mathrm{E}z = 0$,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Cov}(\Sigma^{1/2}z, \mu^{\mathrm{T}}A\Sigma^{1/2}z)
= \mathrm{E}[\Sigma^{1/2}z z^{\mathrm{T}} \Sigma^{1/2} A \mu]
= \Sigma A \mu,
\end{align*}
which yields the result.

Comment: I dont understand how you expanded from this equation to: $Cov(+Σ^{1/2},(+Σ^{1/2})^T(+Σ^{1/2})) = Cov(Σ^{1/2},^TΣ^{1/2}Σ^{1/2}+2^TΣ^{1/2})$

Comment: more specifically this part $(+Σ^{1/2})^(+Σ^{1/2})$

Comment: That comes from the fact that the covariance of a constant with any random variable is $0$. So the $\mu$ term on the left-hand-side and the $\mu^{\mathrm{T}}A\mu$ term after expanding the right-hand-side don't contribute to the covariance.

Comment: I understand that part, but its the expansion of the second term that stumps me:
$(+Σ^{1/2})^(+Σ^{1/2}) = (^Σ^{1/2}Σ^{1/2}+2^Σ^{1/2})$

Comment: That's just the quadratic expansion $(\mu + \Sigma^{1/2}z)^{\mathrm{T}} A (\mu + \Sigma^{1/2}z) = \mu^{\mathrm{T}} A \mu + 2 \mu^{\mathrm{T}} A \Sigma^{1/2} z + z^{\mathrm{T}} \Sigma^{1/2} A \Sigma^{1/2} z$, where the first term is constant and so doesn't contribute any covariance